# Can't find the ERB gem

Tags: ruby, erb

I know how to use erb, and have done so on rails and in standalone ruby apps.. I don't know where it came from, as I have never installed it but it's there. I used rbenv on my mac.

I installed ruby on a windows 8 computer using the rails installer and can't seem to access erb.

how do you install erb??? (Or is there something I'm missing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) module comes with *standard libaray* in Ruby. You just need to require it.

```
require 'erb'

temp = "<%= var %>"

erb = ERB.new(temp)
var = "hi" 
erb.result(binding) # => "hi"
```

Comment: thanks, then I can't understand why it will work on mac but not windows

Comment: It shouldn't be like that.. What is it saying ?

Comment: il have to check.. not on the computer until tuesday

Comment: and 2 years later i still have not checked... sorry